# How to perform auto resize a uiview without device orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, autoresizingmask, uideviceorientation

How to perform `auto resizing` a `UIView` without device orientation?
On current device orientation I want to set `UIView` to be autoresized when it get presented on screen of iPhone.

Comment: Confusing question.Can you elaborate?

Comment: While loading uiview in viewcontroller I want to resize it according to device current orienation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best strategy will be using new auto layout feature from iOS 6 and greater and its more optimized for Xcode 5.

You don't have to make separate views in autolayout for portrait or landscape mode unless there is specific requirement for you UI. Your basic views will look same for landscape and portrait both.

For getting started with Autolayout you can check this tutorial you will get to learn all the basics in this.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Hope this helps. :)